# How can I make my browser(s) finish AJAX requests instead of stopping them when I switch to another page?

Tags: browser

I usually need to deal with things on a page right before switching to yet another page, this ranges from "liking / upvoting a comment or post" up to "an important action" and doesn't always come with feedback on whether the action actually proceeded.

This is a huge problem! I assume the action to proceed once I start the particular AJAX request, but because I switch to another page it didn't actually happen because the AJAX request got aborted. This has left me several times with coming back to the page and seeing my action didn't take place at all; to give you an idea how bad this is, this even happened once when commenting on Super User!

Is there a way to tell my browser to not drop these AJAX connections but simply let them finish?

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do is just install the [FireBug extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firebug/) for Firefox.

Now after installing, press <kbd>F12</kbd> to open the visited web page in the Network panel. It shows all requests including your AJAX request.

The failed requests are shown in red. Now right click it and click *Resend*. It sends the request without loading the page again.

[image]

Comment: As far as I can tell, the OP wants to have AJAX requests finish, not resend them if they failed – because they can do that anyway when they come back to the page.

Comment: ^ What slhck said.

Comment: slhck Tom says that when he switching a TAB ajax requests are failed.now to send that request again.. he has to resend them and that may be done without loading the page as my answer..